# Почему изображения относят к неструктурированным данным?

Tags: изображения, графика

Ведь нам же известен формат. Мы знаем где лежит значение пикселя с нужными нам координатами. В общем все упорядочено. Так почему относят к неструктурированным данным?

Comment: Такого термина даже нет в Википедии.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это зависит от задачи. С точки зрения базы данных, например, конкретные пиксели нерелевантны, поскольку база данных не "заглядывает" внутрь картинки. Точно так же и архив для базы данных -- тоже "чёрный ящик": ей неинтересен тот факт, что *в принципе* можно выяснить, какие данные лежат внутри.

С другой стороны, для просмотрщика картинок изображения ещё как структурированы! Потому что те самые "пиксели с нужными координатами" здесь очень и очень важны.

Можно вполне представить себе базу данных, которая умеет делать запросы типа "дайте мне все картинки, где количество зелёных пикселей больше количества синих", или допустим "все картинки тёплых тонов". Для такой базы данных картинки уже не будут неструктурированными данными, разумеется.

Заметьте, что программа выигрывает от того, что считает какие-то данные неструктурированными, поскольку не нужно заниматься разбором этих данных, их можно просто копировать, не заботясь о смысле. Поэтому при возможности разработчики, конечно же, объявляют данные типа картинок неструктурированными, чтобы избежать необходимости понимать структуру этих данных.

Резюме: если программа *может* абстрагироваться от содержимого данных, она может себе и позволить роскошь считать данные неструктурированными. Если нет, то нет.